# Linker error "... .obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function"

Tags: c++, linker

I have read all the previous replies or solutions for the same linker problem. I understand that the Linker is unable to access the library file that has the functions defined but still I have no luck in solving it!

The errors:

```
1>trial_12th.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _viStatusDesc@12 referenced in function _main
1>trial_12th.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _viClose@4 referenced in function _main
1>trial_12th.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _viRead@16 referenced in function _main
1>trial_12th.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _viWrite@16 referenced in function _main
1>trial_12th.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _viOpen@20 referenced in function _main
1>trial_12th.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _viOpenDefaultRM@4 referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\41kchoudhary\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\trial_12th\Debug\trial_12th.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

I am trying to send and receive data from a mixed-signal oscilloscope. In doing so I am required to write a .cpp file using the pre-defined commands/functions defined using Microsoft Visual Studio C++. I have read the user manual for using these commands, and I also have the header files and libraries required to implement it.

I am using the following code:

```
#include <visa.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     ViSession rm = VI_NULL, vi = VI_NULL;
     ViStatus status;
     ViChar buffer[256];
     ViUInt32 retCnt;

     // Open a default session
     status = viOpenDefaultRM(&rm);
     if (status < VI_SUCCESS) goto error;

     // Open the GPIB device at primary address 1, GPIB board 8
     status = viOpen(rm, "USB::0x0699::0x0377::C011104::INSTR", VI_NULL, VI_NULL,
     &vi);
     if (status < VI_SUCCESS) goto error;

     // Send an ID query.
     status = viWrite(vi, (ViBuf) "*idn?", 5, &retCnt);
     if (status < VI_SUCCESS) goto error;

     // Clear the buffer and read the response
     memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
     status = viRead(vi, (ViBuf) buffer, sizeof(buffer), &retCnt);
     if (status < VI_SUCCESS) goto error;

     // Print the response
     printf("id: %s\n", buffer);

     // Clean up
     viClose(vi); // Not needed, but makes things a bit more

     // understandable
     viClose(rm); // Closes resource manager and any sessions

     // opened with it
     return 0;

     error:
         // Report error and clean up
             viStatusDesc(vi, status, buffer);
             fprintf(stderr, "failure: %s\n", buffer);
             if (rm != VI_NULL) {
                 viClose(rm);
             }
             return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you included the .lib file(s)?

Comment: You forgot to link against the library containing those `Vi*` symbols.

Comment: This is likely a 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue (presuming the .lib file has been added to the project). I had this problem too. I resolved it by following the instructions in the manual, page 5-2 for the TDS2000 series, creating a new project from scratch (e.g. not converting the .dsw project - most likely this was due to getting a 64-bit application/project): Not using precompiled headers, "Win32" for the project template "Win32 Console Application", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add either visa32.lib or visa64.lib to your linker settings.

One way to do that is to use a pragma in your compiler source file:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"visa32.lib")
```

If it is still not found then adjust your lib paths in your IDE or include the full path in the pragma.

Comment: @ArgumentNullException:  I have included the .lib file as follows project -> properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies

Comment: @Haroogan: I think I have included the .lib file as commented above

Comment: You'll need to find visa32.lib somewhere on your machine. It's typically in a subfolder of IVI Foundation under one of the program files folders. Whatever folder it is in needs to be in your project's list of library folders or in Visual Studio's [list of library folders](http://www.lavishsoft.com/wiki/index.php/Visual_Studio_Paths) or you can specify visa23.lib with a full path.

Comment: I have included the path of the visa32.lib file in my project but still its not working :(                                      (path of the file: IVI Foundation -> VISA -> Win64 -> Lib_x64 -> msc -> visa32.lib)

Comment: That folder should be for the 64-bit library. Use the one under `IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\lib\msc`.

Comment: Thank you so much its working now!!!!!!    :) I found the file but in some other IVI Foundation folder as pointed out by Tom Blodget, I was using the 64-bit library :P

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I figured out that you have to add visa32.lib in additional dependencies under the linker properties of your project

Go to your

> project properties -> Linker ->  Additional Dependencies-> Click Down Arrow -> "Edit -> Type visa32.lib

> Click Ok, Ok